# Civilization 5 vs Rise of Nation

Tags: civilization-5, rise-of-nations

I really enjoyed [Rise of Nations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_of_Nations) and with all the Civi 5 questions popping up here, how is Civilization 5 different than Rise of Nations? Rise of Nations employed the concept of territory but also had RTS elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rise of Nations was an RTS, with a few elements borrowed from turn-based strategy.  Civ 5 is a pretty textbook turn-based game.  So I don't think there are a whole lot of similarities other than the general theme, and the fact that different nations have unique powers.  The scope of Civ 5 is much greater, in terms of size of the map, number of cities you control, number of buildings/units/techs, etc.  The economy is more detailed, and you have to worry about city-level management more.  There is a much greater emphasis on diplomacy and trading with other civs and city-states.  Combat is more high level.  And obviously being turn-based, there is no advantage to being able to think/click quickly (though I haven't tried the simultaneous turn multiplayer yet).